# NumPy. Нужно вывести новый массив из массива b с типом данных из массива a/

Tags: python, numpy

Задача:

На вход поступают две строки, состоящие из чисел, разделённых пробелом.

Необходимо создать два массива numpy a и b, в которые поместить эти числа. При этом нужно правильно определить какой тип использовать, исходя из данных, содержащихся в строках.

Затем на основе данных второго массива b необходимо создать третий c, значения которого взяты из второго массива b, а тип данных равен типу данных первого массива a.
Полученные три массива a, b, c вывести на экран в порядке их создания через пробел.

```
import numpy as np

a = input().split()
b = input().split()
c = b[:]

for i in a:
    if '.' in i:
        print(np.array(a, dtype=np.float32))
        break
    else:
        print(np.array(a, dtype=np.int32))
        break

for i in b:
    if '.' in i:
        print(np.array(b, dtype=np.float32))
        break
    else:
        print(np.array(b, dtype=np.int32))
        break
        
print(np.array(c,astype(a))
```

Comment: 1) Вы забыли задать вопрос. 2) Код лежит в правильном направлении, но надо над ним ещё работать и работать. Хинты: 1) Точка может быть и не в первом же элементе массива. 2) Вы никуда не записываете то, что печатаете. 3) У вас два однотипных куска кода с циклом, имеет смысл вынести этот код в функцию, чтобы уменьшить повторы. 4) Тип массива лежит в свойстве массива `dtype`.